# Symfony 2 - Two level nested form

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, nested

I am new with Symfony 2 and I have to say that I still don't get everything about it, here is what I'm trying to achieve.
On a "Quiz" page, an admin add a new quiz, as he does that he can dynamically add new questions, as many as he wants using jQuery and a nested form "question". A second level is then being created, for each question he creates, he can create answers, and select one or more as the righ answer, basically leaving me with multiple choice questionaire.

I managed to get everything working exept for the data persistance T_T

```
 ErrorHandler ->handle ('2', 'spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given', 
'C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php', '1367', array(**'entity'** => array('qContent' => 'Test QuestionContent', 'qType' => '2', 'answer' => array(array('aContent' => 'Test AswerContent', 'isRight' => '1'))), 'assume' => '2'))
```

I understand that Doctrine wants an entity instead of an array, but how can I persist what my form returns without having to completely rebuild the data persisting process?!

Ok, you have waited long enough, here is the code ^^

**AddQuiz Controler:**

```
 public function addQuizAction($lesson)
    {
        $new_quiz = new Quiz;

        //Find the lesson entity
        $repository = $this ->getDoctrine()
                             ->getManager()
                             ->getRepository('InkyCourseBundle:Lesson');
        $lessonRep = $repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $lesson));

        // Create Quiz


        if ($this->getUser()) { $new_quiz->setUser($this->getUser());}
        if ($lessonRep) { $new_quiz->setLesson($lessonRep);}

        $form = $this->createForm(new QuizType(), $new_quiz);
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($new_quiz);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Quiz bien ajouté');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('quiz_edit', array('id' => $new_quiz->getId(),'lesson' => $lesson)));
            }
        }
```

**Answer Entity:**

```
namespace Inky\QuizBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Answer
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="aContent", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $aContent;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isRight", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isRight;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="Answer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Inky\UserBundle\Entity\User")
    */
    private $user;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set aContent
     *
     * @param string $aContent
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setAContent($aContent)
    {
        $this->aContent = $aContent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get aContent
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAContent()
    {
        return $this->aContent;
    }

    /**
     * Set isRight
     *
     * @param boolean $isRight
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setIsRight($isRight)
    {
        $this->isRight = $isRight;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isRight
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsRight()
    {
        return $this->isRight;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $question
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setQuestion(\Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\Question $question = null)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return \Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\Question 
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }
}
```

**Question Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Inky\QuizBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qContent", type="text")
     */
    private $qContent;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qType", type="smallint")
     */
    private $qType;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quiz", inversedBy="Question")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $quiz;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="Question")
     */
    private $answer;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set qContent
     *
     * @param string $qContent
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQContent($qContent)
    {
        $this->qContent = $qContent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get qContent
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getQContent()
    {
        return $this->qContent;
    }

    /**
     * Set qType
     *
     * @param integer $qType
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQType($qType)
    {
        $this->qType = $qType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get qType
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQType()
    {
        return $this->qType;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->answer = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $question
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQuestion(\Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $question = null)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return \Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz 
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Add answer
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Answer $answer
     * @return Question
     */
    public function addAnswer(\Inky\QuizBundle\Answer $answer)
    {
        $this->answer[] = $answer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove answer
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Answer $answer
     */
    public function removeAnswer(\Inky\QuizBundle\Answer $answer)
    {
        $this->answer->removeElement($answer);
    }

    /**
     * Get answer
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAnswer()
    {
        return $this->answer;
    }

    /**
     * Set quiz
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $quiz
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQuiz(\Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $quiz = null)
    {
        $this->quiz = $quiz;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quiz
     *
     * @return \Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz 
     */
    public function getQuiz()
    {
        return $this->quiz;
    }
}
```

**Quiz Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Inky\QuizBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Quiz
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\QuizRepository")
 */
class Quiz
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isPublic", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isPublic;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\Question", mappedBy="Quiz")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Inky\CourseBundle\Entity\Lesson")
     */
    private $lesson;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set descritpion
     *
     * @param string $descritpion
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setDescritpion($descritpion)
    {
        $this->descritpion = $descritpion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descritpion
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescritpion()
    {
        return $this->descritpion;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set isPublic
     *
     * @param boolean $isPublic
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setIsPublic($isPublic)
    {
        $this->isPublic = $isPublic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isPublic
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsPublic()
    {
        return $this->isPublic;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->question = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add question
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $question
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function addQuestion(\Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $question)
    {
        $this->question[] = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove question
     *
     * @param \Inky\QuizBundle\Quiz $question
     */
    public function removeQuestion(\Inky\QuizBundle\Entity\Quiz $question)
    {
        $this->question->removeElement($question);
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Set lesson
     *
     * @param \Inky\CourseBundle\Entity\Lesson $lesson
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setLesson(\Inky\CourseBundle\Entity\Lesson $lesson = null)
    {
        $this->lesson = $lesson;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lesson
     *
     * @return \Inky\CourseBundle\Entity\Lesson 
     */
    public function getLesson()
    {
        return $this->lesson;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Quiz
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

**Question Type:**

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('qContent')
            ->add('qType')
            ->add('answer', 'collection', array('type' => new AnswerType(),
                                                'allow_add' => true,
                                                'allow_delete' => true,
                                                'prototype' => true,
                                                'prototype_name' => '__char_prot__'))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null
        ));
    }
```

**Answer Type:**

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('aContent')
            ->add('isRight')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null
        ));
    }
```

I hope that I have been clear and that all od this code does not confuse you too much, the view if executed with some javascript. I repost the Error just in case you missed it, or simply don't want to scroll back up:
    ErrorHandler ->handle ('2', 'spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given', 
    'C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php', '1367', array(**'entity'** => array('qContent' => 'Test QuestionContent', 'qType' => '2', 'answer' => array(array('aContent' => 'Test AswerContent', 'isRight' => '1'))), 'assume' => '2'))

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)?

Comment: Shouldn't the data_class of your question type be your question entity?

Comment: Freetrace & Bjuice: The two of you are orienting me towards two different paths, either transform the data I have in an array via data transforming, or change the data_class to have my resutls be object of my class question (and answer^^). I have learned a lot with your tips thank you!
I have decided to go with the second option: change 'data_class'es of question and answer and after some altering everything works fine, but it seems like the foreign key 'quiz_id' in the question database as well as 'question_id' in answer are not getting updated.
In other words the link answer=>question=>quiz

Comment: does not exist in my DB T_T.
Is there a problem in my annotations?
PS: the data_transform was a great tip, but created a lot more problems than solutions.